# Loading Image in Java using JFrame

Tags: java, swing

so i have a very basic java application, there is a panel and inside that is a button. When a user clicks the button, i want a picture to come up in another panel in the same form.

I searched up ways to load images from web/from my folder and this is the code i've come up with:-

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)

{                                       
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("URL-of-the-image");
    panel2.setIcon(icon);

}
```

[~~what panel 2 looks like~~](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruGRK.png)

where am i going wrong?
it says that the method "setIcon()" is causing a problem but i don't know any other method to do this job. Please Guide!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: for the method "setIcon", it says "cannot find symbol"

Comment: So it doesn't compile?

Comment: If it is a `JPanel`, it doesn't have a `setIcon` method, you may want to use a `JLabel` instead .

Comment: no it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Berger could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: @SakazukiAkainu : yes see the edit above .

Comment: Use JavaFX.. ;)

Comment: @Berger can you put your comment in an answer so that I can +1 it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `panel2` is a [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), it doesn't have a `setIcon` method.

Use a [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) instead , it has such a method.